# Formal way of writing the Binomial Expansion for Derivatives

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm currently in an Advanced Calculus class where we are currently talking about derivatives of functions of several variables, and I came across the following question:

> Find the tenth differential, $d^{10}f$, of $f(x,y)=\ln(x+y)$.

After finding a few of the early differentials, I noticed that they followed a similar pattern of the Binomial Theorem for polynomials, e.g., 
$$d^4f=\frac{-(3!)}{(x+y)^4}(dx^4+4\,dx^3dy+6\,dx^2dy^2+4dx\,dy^3+dy^4),\tag{$\star$}$$ where everything in the parentheses is the fourth row of Pascal's Triangle.

So my question is:

$\textbf{Is there a formal shorthand for writing such differentials?}$

Am I okay to write my fourth differential as I did in $(\star)$?

Could I write an arbitrary $n$th differential as $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!}{(x+y)^n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\!{n \choose k}dx^{n-k}\,dy^{k}$ ?

(E.g., $(\star)$ could be written $\frac{(-1)^{5}(3)!}{(x+y)^4} \sum\limits_{k=0}^4\!{4 \choose k}dx^{4-k}\,dy^{k}$ )

Or are both just informal nonsense?

Note: [I am assuming that $dx\,dy=dy\,dx$ since $x+y=0$ is excluded in the domain of $f$, which means all partial derivatives will be continuous on the same domain.]

Comment: The shorthand you wrote does have an actual meaning to it, and can be justified rigorously using concepts in differential geometry. For example, see [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Higher-order_differentials) where a generalization of the formula you derived appears, with some discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing the $n$-th derivative of a function $f(x)$ as $f^{(n)}(x)$ or $\frac{\mathrm{d}^nf}{\mathrm{d}x^n}$ is commonplace, and your notation is not far from that; I doubt anybody with a mathematical background will have problems understanding what you mean!

Edit: If you are writing a paper or a piece of coursework of some sort, you could define the notation at the beginning just to be safe.